# how to define container templated with enum

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I need to create a container which holds integer and templated with enum.

```
 enum Color{R,G,B};

 template<class Color C,//class before color will be removed
 template <class, class = allocator<int>> class Container>
 class MyClass
 {
    Container<int> buffer;
 }
```

I need to create vector and list out of it. Something like:

```
 MyClass<Color::R, std::list> mbs
 MyClass<Color::G, std::vector> mbs

 //wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 MyClass<Color C, vector> v1;

 //for contaner
 Container<int>::iterator nth = buffer.begin()
```

Comment: Yep, that's the general form for non-type template parameters.

Comment: please dont fix your code according to answers. this makes your question completely pointless. Actually I vote to close it because I am not sure how to revert the edits to make it a meaningful question again

Comment: yeap that is working. Could i ask you how to create an object now?

Comment: @ArtemTarasenkov: tobi303 is right; when you edit your question according to the answers, it makes the question pointless and the answers meaningless. I have tried to reconstruct your original question + iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)

For your container it would be defined like so:

```
template<Color C, 
         template<class, class = std::allocator<int>> class Container>
class MyClass{
   Container<int> buffer;
   // ...
};
```

You can create an instance like so:

```
MyClass<Color::R, std::vector> instance;
```

You can create an iterator like so:

```
typename Container<int>::iterator iter = buffer.begin();
```

`typename` is required because `iterator` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)

Comment: Yeap, works better, thank you, but how do i create an object of it now?

Comment: @ArtemTarasenkov: See my update. You need to specify a specific `Color` in the template arguments; it cannot be a variable.

Comment: changed it this way, and have updated my question with console output

Comment: works well! Thanks. Last question... how to get an iterator from this container? I have updated the question.

Comment: @ArtemTarasenkov With `buffer.begin()` and `buffer.end()`, as usual. What’s the issue?

Comment: @AndyG i can assign it only to auto i = buffer.begin(), but what actually should go instead of auto? As well how to define size for iteration?